# How to infer the eigenvalue distribution from matrix where each entry has a known Gaussian distribution?

Tags: random-matrices, eigenvalues, bayesian-probability

## Problem

Given $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ where $X_{ij} \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_{ij}, \sigma_{ij}^2 I)$

Find the marginal distribution of each eigenvalue, using whatever you can.

## Background

In my field, I have a Bayesian inference framework that will obtain the $X$ distribution, but what we really need is the eigenvalue distribution of the matrix $X$.

## Question

1. Is this problem well defined?
2. Is the only way to infer it through sampling in such **high dimensional** space and then for each realization of the matrix, do the eigenvalue decomposition?

Comment: Do you want the joint distribution of all eigenvalues or just the eigenvalue density?

Comment: @Marcel, just for each eigenvalue, what is the density/distribution. However, I think I can draw distribution but it becomes very ambiguous to me that, since eigenvalue decomposition algorithm usually giving eigenvalue in a descending order, it becomes rather difficult to tell, each computed  eigenvalue, is a result of which eigenmode.

Comment: Your question was not very clear, and your comment made it even less so. What do you mean, "for each eigenvalue, what is the density"? It is not clear if you want 1) The eigenvalue density, which is an overall quantity, 2) The density of each eigenvalue in order, i.e. the largest one, the second-largest, etc., 3) The joint distribution. These questions are all very different from each other.

Comment: there is really no hope to have a closed-form expression for any $n$; for small $n=2,3,\ldots$ you can just calculate the eigenvalue density by hand (this is one single function, not a separate function for each eigenvalue); for larger $n$ just run a computer simulation.

Comment: @thedude, I was hoping to get something about how does the distribution looks like. I know getting the exact distribution analytically is impossible. And only hope to get the shape of distribution in the eigenvalue phase space, i.e., the two dimensional space.

Comment: @thedude I want the marginal distribution of each eigenvalue.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker I just want to know how they look like, or if there is any analytical property or analytical distribution form. If I know how they look like, even though that usually does not have a closed-form solution, I can use machine learning to approximate those distributions.

Comment: I am sorry, but there is no such thing as the "marginal distribution of each eigenvalue". Every eigenvalue has the same marginal distribution, because the order of the eigenvalues is arbitrary. You might be interested in the order statistics, which asks for the distribution of the largest eigenvalue, or the next-to-largest eigenvalue, but that is a very different problem.

Comment: The problem becomes better defined (though still hard) if you want the marginal distribution of _singular_ values (which seems more likely to be relevant for statistical applications), because those come with a natural order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a $2 \times 2$ example to consider. Since each entry has its own distribution, let three of them have standard deviation $0$ and the matrix be $\left[ \begin {array}{cc} 0&X_{12}\\ 1&0\end {array} \right]$ with the mean and standard deviation of $X_{12}=\mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$ to be determined. The eigenvalues are either

- $\pm t$ if $X_{12}=-t^2 \leq 0$ or
- $\pm ti$ if $X_{12}=t^2 \geq 0$

So the mean is distributed as the trace (which is always the case).

For $\mu=0$ and $\sigma=1$ one will have the eigenvalues real or pure imaginary with equal probability and inside the unit circle with probability about $\frac23.$  Is that the kind of result you seek?

There is a very large literature on random matrices although it usually concentrates on the matrix being symmetric or Hermetian and drawn from $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ with respect to some Gaussian distribution.